# Need to make my Mysql Slave a read only server

Tags: mysql, replication, readonly, slave

i just moved out RDS and setup my own Master/Slave mysql replication.

The replication is working fine, but my slave node is accepting changes, differently of what happened on RDS (the server generated an error saying that the server was on read only mode).

I trie to activate on my my.cnf the configuration read_only = ON (on the slave)...
but even after a service restart, the server continues to accept changes.
[image]

What am i doing wrong? I want that the servers accepts changes ONLY from the replication connection...

Answer (score 1):

Just found it...I was using root user, and root can do anything.... for user without super privileges, the read-only IS working.

Comment: Point of clarification:  `root` cannot *necessarily* "do anything" -- it is not a magical username.  It only has the `SUPER` privilege because that's conventionally the username of the privileged account.  Any user with `SUPER` has the same level of privilege (and thus should not be used for routine operations, since `@@READ_ONLY` does not apply to `SUPER`).  On RDS, of course, your admin account lacks `SUPER`, even if you call it 'root'.